# How to get details from a Guzzle ConnectException

Tags: guzzle, google-api-php-client

I'm using the lats version of the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client on php 8.1.11 for Google Sheets.

I import datas with a pasteDataRequest(). I very often catch a Guzzle ConnectException with the error "Connection refused".

Despite this error, the datas are written but I wouldlike (and I don't see how) catch a most detailed error to know why Google send me a Connection Refused.

Any idea ?

Thanks